# Identify sinus behavior on a data stream

Tags: data-science, data-analysis, trigonometry

I want to identify when data values ordered as a sine **waveform**.

For example in the picture

[image: data that I want to identify for example]

Until now I have worked with features like **STD**, **RMS** etc, on the data to identify **waveforms**. Now I am looking for a feature which will have such functionality although I am opened for any ideas to achieve such identification.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, compute the Fourier transform and see if it has a noticeable peak at one of the frequencies.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can fft feature extraction can do it? also I found more possible answers in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141342/identifying-common-periodic-waveforms-square-sine-sawtooth